# 3*012 = 30 and not 36. Why is that?

Tags: java, operators

I am confused why this is and I cannot seem to find an answer why. This is from the assignment:

```
x=1, y=2, z=3;

z=(int)(x/y*3.0+z*012);

System.out.printf("%d %d %d", x, y, z);
```

Answer is :

```
1 2 30; << from eclipse
```

How I arrived here:

`(1/2) = 0 * 3.0 = 0 + (z*012)= 30`. I wanted to say 36 but I guess it is 30 according to the IDE.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`012` is octal number not decimal which decimal value is 10.

```
z=(int)(x/y*3.0+z*012);
```

is equals -

```
z=(int)(1/2*3.0+3*10);
```

- For reference

Numeric starts with 0 is octal number.
Numeric starts with 0x is hexadecimal number.
Numeric starts with 0b or OB is binary number.(Since Java edition 7 - [Binary Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/binary-literals.html))

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. Why my professor did not point this out is very strange to me...unless that was the point :)

Answer (score 4):

In Java and several other languages, an integer literal beginning with `0` is interpreted as an octal (`base 8`) quantity. Here `012` is an octal number which has a decimal value f `10`

So your multiplication will come like

```
z = (int) (1/2 * 3.0 + 3 * 10);
```

From [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1)

> An octal numeral consists of an ASCII digit 0 followed by one or more
>   of the ASCII digits 0 through 7 interspersed with underscores, and can
>   represent a positive, zero, or negative integer.

Answer (score 3):

`012` is an octal, because it starts with `0`:

```
012 = (0 * 8^2) + (1 * 8^1) + (2) = 10
```

Therefore:

```
012 * 3 = 10 * 3 = 30
```

**Notes:**

- Remember that an octal is a number in base 8 (decimal is base 10), so it can't have digits larger or equal to 8.
- Similarly, hexadecimal numbers starts with `0x`, for example: `0x12 = 1*16 + 2 = 18`

Comment: can you add parenthesis this will explain more better

Answer (score 2):

See the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html):

> An octal numeral consists of an ASCII digit **0 followed by one or more
>   of the ASCII digits 0 through 7** interspersed with underscores, and can
>   represent a positive, zero, or negative integer.

So,

012 = 0 * 8<sup>2</sup> + 1 * 8<sup>1</sup> + 2 * 8<sup>0</sup> = 10

In Java 7, you can use [underscores in numeric literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html) which might help you interrupting the value.